# Taking file input from vue and push to Python code

Tags: javascript, python, api, vue.js, flask

I have a Vue project and one python script. I want to input a file using Vue and use that uploaded file in python scrpit.
Right now I have two completely different Vue project and python file not integrated together.
How should I do it?
Any suggestions?

Comment: You've put `flask` as a tag. Please show what you've already done with flask for file uploading.

Comment: i havent used flask at all. I know flask is a way but i dont want to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer the API Rest mechanism as an option.
For example, see the following code:

```
<form id="form" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      @change="onUploadFile">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
</form>

onUploadFile: function (event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    axios.post('upload_file', file, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

And in Python you should get this POST method!

Comment: Can you please explain this code, I'm new to vue and having trouble to understand

Comment: Please  read and practice this tutorial: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/file-upload-using-vue-js-axios-phpexample.html

Comment: I am getting this error:  ```  POST http://localhost:8080/api.php 404 (Not Found)``` @Sherzod

Comment: `import requests
import json
x = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/api.php')

print(x.text)`          This is python code. @Sherzod